# I need to make an AI that makes random O's in my TIC TAC TOE program

Tags: python, function, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

ive been looking around on questions on AI's and it looks like each AI is unique to the program and none of them are helping.

I want to have the computer to draw the O's randomly after my turn as the X. I have heard that minimax might help but I dont understand it. I am still a beginner in programming.

How do I get the O's to draw by the computer after my turn(the first turn,user is the X's)?

This is my tic tac toe program so far. Docstrings and comments tell you more about the program.

```
import turtle

#I need to fix the positions of the X and O's so that they draw more perfectly into the squares of the board.
class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.u__init_board = []

    def draw_board():
        '''draws a tic-tac-toe board over the 9 turtle squares'''
        t=turtle.Turtle()
        t.ht() # makes the turtle invisable
        t.up()
        t.goto(-40,-40)
        t.down()
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(80)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(80)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.goto(-40,-40)
        t.left(180)
        t.forward(160)
        t.up()
        t.goto(40,-40)
        t.down()
        t.forward(240)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(80)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(240)

    def setup_board():
        '''Creates 3 rows of 3 turtles using range(0, 240, 80); turtle.Turtle(); up(); shape('square'); shapesize(4, 4, 4);
        color('white'); goto(x, y). Each turtle is registered to respond to click events using onclick(mark).
        Calls draw_grid() once the 9 turtles are on the board.'''
        for y in range(0,240,80):
            for x in range (0,240,80):
             t=turtle.Turtle()
             t.up()
             t.shape('square')
             t.shapesize(4,4,4,)
             t.color('white')
             t.goto(x,y)
             t.onclick(TicTacToe.mark)
        TicTacToe.draw_board()

    def mark(x, y):

        '''Function is invoked whenever a turtle registered to respond to click event is clicked. Creates a turtle and draws
        either a circle or an x centered on the x, y coordinates of the click.
        Be sure to set circle to False once the circle is drawn and to True once the x is drawn. '''
        ct = turtle.Turtle()
        ct.ht() #hides the turtle (makes the turtle invisable)
        ct.up()
        global circle
        if circle:
            turtle.penup()
            #turtle.speed(0)
            turtle.goto(x,y)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.circle(30)
            turtle.left(45)
            circle = False
        else:
            turtle.up()
            #turtle.speed(0)
            turtle.goto(x,y)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.left(45)
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(180)
            turtle.forward(80)
            turtle.left(180)
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(180)
            turtle.forward(80)
            circle = True

    def main():
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        wn.title('OG Tic Tac Toe')
        wn.bgcolor("red")
        global circle
        circle = False
        TicTacToe.setup_board()
        return 'Done'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TicTacToe.main()
    turtle.TK.mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't really an AI problem: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: Look at the Minimax theory - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

Comment: If the computer player was supposed to do anything remotely intelligent, minimax would be a standard starting point. For random moves, it's not relevant.

Comment: Please be specific: What is your program doing? WHat do you want it to do? Yo say you need to fix the positions so that they draw more perfectly? How are they imperfect? You say you need to generate random positions... why is the random package insufficient?

Comment: Read my program comments for my program details. I told you what I want to do in the description. Please Read the question more carefully before you down vote my question...

Comment: Your comments have very little to do with your question. Reading the comments, it would look like your question is about fixing the graphics alignment.

Comment: Sheena was asking about what my program is doing so i referred her/him to my comments. @sheena i also meant my docstrings

Comment: You have said what your final goal is - to draw Os randomly. Is your question a: how to draw Os. b. how to select a position from a list of available positions. c. something else? Also: What have you tried, what is the expected output? What is the actual output? What is the problem you are facing? Saying 'my goal is X and here is all the code' is not a specific question.

Comment: I want to have the computer to draw the O's randomly after my turn as the X. I have heard that minimax might help but I dont understand it. I am still a beginner in programming. The part of the point of posting your code is for people to test out the program.

Comment: QUESTION IS: "How do I get the O's to draw by the computer after my turn?"

Comment: If you want "random", what do you need AI for?  Just select a random location.

Comment: Is your problem with every single one of: 1: find a way to keep track of what positions are available. 2: Choose a position for an O (lookup the random module, what you are doing is not AI at all). 3: draw some stuff. Another problem you face, as Steve mentioned, is that your code is all lumped together. Separation of responsibilities makes code easier to fix (among other things).. SO is not just for answering immediate concerns, it's a resource. If you make your questions specific then the answers will more likely work and be more likely to help someone else.

Comment: And as for your question about downvotes: there is a reason why that stuff is anonymous

Comment: Haha now I know its you smh get outta here

Comment: TicTacToe is a matter of learning the moves, not of intelligence. I think a look-up table (LUT) would be more appropriate than an AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General advice:

Separate the logic from the GUI then you will see that you have a grid of 9 squares some blank some with X and some with O - keep a list of blank ones and pick one at random, draw your O and remove it from the list.  Simples!

## Code Outline:

```
#### GUI Stuff ####
def DrawBoard():
    """ Draw The Blank Board and Connect The Mouse Hander """

def DrawSymbol(TileNo, XorO):
    """ Draw the required X or O symbol in tile number 0..9 """

def OnMouseClick():
    """ Convert the mouse click event to a tile number in the range 0..8 and call Square Picked as a user."""

def ShowWin(WinningTiles):
    """ Highlight the winning list of tiles """

### Game Logic ###
def SquarePicked(Square, UserOrComputer):
    """
    When a given square is picked check if it has already been taken, if it has then return false otherwise call update square and return true 
    """

def UpdateSquare(Square, UserOrComputer):
    """
    Update the list of squares to show it taken, update the board, then call check for win
    if it returns false and this was a user go call computer go.
    """

def CheckForWin():
    """
    Run through the list of squares to check for a win and if it has happened call ShowWin.
    """

def ComputerGo():
    """
    Pick a (random)) square from those not taken and call square picked.
    """
```

Comment: What do you mean by seperate the logic from the gui?

Comment: All the code above is about drawing things - have one bit of code for drawing and mouse handling and another for the (game) logic.  This is always good design as if your drawing environment changes you know which bit to change and the logic of the operation is disentangled from the GUI.

Comment: Can you share some code that would keep track of mouse movement?

Comment: You already have some `t.onclick` tells you when the mouse clicks on a given "turtle"!

Comment: What would your answer look like in code then? I'm still not understanding this